# Show that two rings of matrices are not isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Let $p$ be a prime number and $$ A_p = \{\left( \begin{matrix}
    a & bp \\
    b & a \\
    \end{matrix} \right)|\ a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \}  $$

Show that $A_2$ and $A_3$ are not isomorphic. The problem had 2 other questions, but this is the one where I got stuck.

I tried by writing $\left( \begin{matrix}
    4 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)$ as$\left( \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right) + \left( \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)$ and as $\left( \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)  \left( \begin{matrix}
    2 & 0 \\
    0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)$ as with $\mathbb{2Z}$ and $\mathbb{3Z}$, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $A_p\cong\Bbb Z[\sqrt p]$ surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on the observation of Lord Shark the Unknown, we see that in $A_2$ there is an element 
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
    0 & 2 \\
    1 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)$$
whose square is $2I$.  In $A_3$ the square of an arbitrary element takes the form
$$\left( \begin{matrix}
    a^2+3b^2 & 6ab \\
    2ab & a^2+3b^2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right)$$
For such an element to equal $2I$ we must have $a=0$ or $b=0$ in which case there is no solution to $a^2+3b^2=2$, so $A_3$ has no element whose square is $2I$.  $A_2$ and $A_3$ cannot be isomorphic.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another way to see it.  If $\phi$ is an isomorphism, then $a$ and $\phi(a)$ satisfy the same polynomials with integer coefficients, so they have the same eigenvalues.  But the eigenvalues of $A_p$ are $a\pm b\sqrt{p}.$